# How to build a hover effect with css only, or css+jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Can you help me to build the hover effect, like on screenshot, with css only? Or, with css+jquery.
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFvWJ.png)

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 make description visible
2 position it
3 profit

example from worked site

css:

```
.m-gallery-product-item .hover-wrap {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}


.m-gallery-product-item .item-main:hover .hover-wrap {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="m-gallery-product-item">
 <div class="item-main">...
  <div class="item-img">,</div>
  <div class="item-info">,</div>
  <div class="hover-wrap"> 
   <div class="hover-main">
    <div class="tags"> ,,,,,,,,, </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

see worked example on ebay.com alibaba.com, many big and popular sell sites used that tick for a long time, just copy-paste it to your code!